# Regex check if string doesn't have any letters except between two special chars

Tags: regex, string, typescript, validation

I was trying to validate whole string if it doesn't contain letters except the letters between two '#'.

So for example:

`#one# + #two#` - is a valid string

`#one# two` - is not a valid string

`#one# + half + #two#` - is not a valid string (#one# and #two# is valid but half shouldn't be left alone.

so odd occurrences of # - opens the space for entering letters and 
even occurrences of # are supposed to close the space where it's possible to write letters.

I managed to create a regex that validates most of the cases, but the last one I couldn't figure out.

here is my regex:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z]*(#.+#)[^a-zA-Z]*$/g
```

here is the site I was testing it: 
https://regexr.com/

Side note: 
If it is not possible by regex, I was thinking about splitting the string on # and then checking the leftovers for letters in typescript.

Any idea how to achieve this kind of validation? 
Thanks

Comment: Probably `^#\w+#\W+#\w+#$` will work for you

Comment: `^(#[A-Za-z]+#[^A-Za-z]*)*$` should work.  \w isn't appropriate because it is the equivalent of A-Za-z_0-9, and \W would not allow numbers or underscores outside of the # symbols (unless that is what you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) match the whole string matching either not a char a-z, newline or a `#` OR match the `#[a-zA-Z]+#` pattern where there can only be char a-z inbetween

```
^(?:[^a-zA-Z\r\n#]|#[a-zA-Z]+#)+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^a-zA-Z#\r\n]` Match any char except the listed
  - `|` Or
  - `#[a-zA-Z]+#` Match `#`, 1+ chars a-zA-Z and `#`
- `)+` Close non capturing group (with the alternation) and repeat 1+ times to avoid matching an empty stirng
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5GR1YV/1)

---

To also match odd occurrences you could use

```
[^a-zA-Z\r\n#]|#[a-zA-Z]+#(?:[a-zA-Z]+#)*)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0K3cB6/1)